# Simplify casting in Go when taking any interface as a parameter

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I have a struct like so,

```golang
//
// HandlerInfo is used by features in order to register a gateway handler
type HandlerInfo struct {
    Fn     func(interface{})
    FnName string
    FnRm   func()
}
```

where I want to pass a func:

```golang
func StarboardReactionHandler(e *gateway.MessageReactionAddEvent) {
 // foo
}

i := HandlerInfo{Fn: StarboardReactionHandler}
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
Cannot use 'StarboardReactionHandler' (type func(e *gateway.MessageReactionAddEvent)) as the type func(interface{})
```

I found this workaround:

```golang
func StarboardReactionHandler(e *gateway.MessageReactionAddEvent) {
 // foo
}

func handlerCast(e interface{}) {
    StarboardReactionHandler(e.(*gateway.MessageReactionAddEvent))
}

i := HandlerInfo{Fn: handlerCast}
```

Is there some way that I can simplify needing `handlerCast`, such as doing it inside my `StarboardReactionHandler` or in `HandlerInfo`? Maybe with generics or reflection? I basically just want to minimize the syntax / boilerplate that's required here.

Comment: That's not a cast, that's a conversion. The conversion involves running actual code at runtime. That code is required.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/n8A6C4Lb8YC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use interface{}.(type)

follow is a exmple:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type HandlerInfo struct {
    Fn     func(interface{})
    FnName string
    FnRm   func()
}
type MessageReactionAddEvent = func(a, b int) int

func StarboardReactionHandler(e interface{}) {
    switch e.(type) {
    case MessageReactionAddEvent:
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", (e.(MessageReactionAddEvent))(1, 2))
    }

}
func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
func main() {
    i := HandlerInfo{Fn: StarboardReactionHandler}
    i.Fn(add)
}
```